# Can't render on floating point RGB texture on Firefox

Tags: firefox, three.js, webgl

I seem to be unable to render on a floating point RGB texture when running on Firefox. Chrome works just fine. Firefox gives me this:

> Framebuffer not complete. (status: 0x8cd6) COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 has an effective format of RGB32F, which is not renderable

I have tried to enable extensions

> console.log(renderer.context.getExtension(‘WEBGL_color_buffer_float’));
>   console.log(renderer.context.getExtension(‘OES_texture_float’));

and both return non-null values, but the rendering still fails.

The code below that shows nothing on screen but renders on an offscreen floating point texture. On firefox the errors will show up on the console.
the code:

```js
var width = 400
var height = 200

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
renderer.setSize(width, height)
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

console.log(renderer.context.getExtension('WEBGL_color_buffer_float'));
console.log(renderer.context.getExtension('OES_texture_float'));

renderer.setClearColor(0x000000)

var scene = new THREE.Scene()
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 32, 32)
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffff00})
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
sphere.position.set(0, 10, 0)
scene.add(sphere)

var target = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(width, height, {
  format: THREE.RGBFormat,
  type: THREE.FloatType,
  minFilter: THREE.NearestFilter,
  magFilter: THREE.NearestFilter,
  stencilBuffer: false,
  depthBuffer: true,
})

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, width / height, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 0)
camera.lookAt(sphere.position);

renderer.render(scene, camera, target, true)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/86/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I suggest you [file a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/). In my machine I also get this error `extension 'GL_ARB_gpu_shader5' is not supported` which is something Firefox itself is injecting into the shaders (an unrelated bug). I'd suggest you make a simple WebGL example though. No need for a giant library. On the other hand, support for rendering to RGB32F textures is not a required feature of WebGL1 even if `WEBGL_color_buffer_float` exists. Still if you tell them it's working in Chrome maybe they'll fix it.

Comment: I just realized `WEBGL_color_buffer_float` actually guarantees support for RGBA32F textures, not RGB32F. Thanks for suggesting that. RGBA32F seems properly supported and working. I will file the bug, maybe they'll do something about it. Thank you!

Comment: [Here's a smaller test](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/4k2jfn24/)